# Flutter Stack Layout Issue: Radio Widgets Not Visible on Linear Progress

Tags: flutter

I'm relatively new to Flutter and currently facing an issue with a stack layout. I am attempting to create a layout where I have a linear progress indicator at the bottom, and on top of it, I want to spread three radio buttons horizontally. However, when I run the app in the Chrome browser, the radio widgets are not visible.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                LinearProgressIndicator(
                  value: 0.1,
                  semanticsLabel: 'Linear progress indicator',
                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey, // Add background color
                  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  left: 0,
                  child: Radio(
                    value: 1,
                    groupValue: null,
                    onChanged: (value) {},
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.075,
                  child: Radio(
                    value: 2,
                    groupValue: null,
                    onChanged: (value) {},
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  right: 0,
                  child: Radio(
                    value: 4,
                    groupValue: null,
                    onChanged: (value) {},
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
```

Comment: "I want to spread three radio buttons horizontally" - use `Row` widget then, more: https://flutter-ko.dev/development/ui/layout/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

To get a UI where there are Radio buttons stacked upon a linear progress indicator, you cloud try using the following code -

```
Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          children: [
            LinearProgressIndicator(
              value: 0.1,
              semanticsLabel: 'Linear progress indicator',
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey, // Add background color
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
            ),
            Positioned(
              child: Radio(
                value: 1,
                groupValue: null,
                onChanged: (value) {},
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.075,
              child: Radio(
                value: 2,
                groupValue: null,
                onChanged: (value) {},
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              right: 0,
              child: Radio(
                value: 4,
                groupValue: null,
                onChanged: (value) {},
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).